# What is this device and what is wrong with it?

Tags: plumbing, water

I have this device in my basement that is hooked up to the water system. I have no idea what it does or even if it works. Why is it covered in that stuff?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sorry for the quality of the last photo.

Comment: The last photo was quite helpful, actually, since it shows the sump pit.

Comment: I actually thought that thing was mounted to the cement floor. I guess I should have looked closer!

Comment: at first glance It looks more like a compressor, but the oblong float hanging off the back in the first photo gave it away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's **the old sump pump**, which was presumably working when the new sump pump was installed, and kept as a spare in case the new sump pump died. It looks about normal for an old sump pump (they sit in water and get cruddy.)

It's not actually "connected" to anything, though there may be a wire taped to the cut-off pipe.

Comment: Oh that makes total sense! I'm guessing the white pipe that is poking up from the sump hole is the new pipe and pump. They must have just cut off  the old one at the pipe for easy removal. Thanks!